# How to move an image up in a div?

Tags: html, css

I have a semi complicated website, and tucked inside a bunch of `<div>` is an image, I need that image to be moved up x number of pixels.  I have the overflow hidden, so that it will cut the image off at the bottom (as expected) but I can't get the image to move where I want it to with the width maintaining 100%, and the image coming from the bottom

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/morty346/d3y4wpbt/1/) of the code

```
#DIV_8 {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 300px;

    overflow: hidden;
}

#DIV_9 {
    max-height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    max-width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain (or show) what should be the result? What you wrote so far is not so clear.

Comment: This should help you :) https://jsfiddle.net/d3y4wpbt/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work by adding:

```
#DIV_9 {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
}
```

Adjusting `top` moves the image up and down.

https://jsfiddle.net/y197yjp2/

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
#DIV_8 {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#DIV_9 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#DIV_9 img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="DIV_1">
  <div id="DIV_2">
    <div id="DIV_3">
      <div id="DIV_4">
        <div id="DIV_5">
          <div id="DIV_6">
            <div id="DIV_7">
              <div id="DIV_8">
                <div id="DIV_9">
                  <img src="http://img11.deviantart.net/a412/i/2012/145/9/9/google_chrome_by_juniorgustabo-d513nlo.png" width="360" height="308" alt="brazil" id="IMG_10" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use negative a negative margin-top

```
#DIV_8 {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 300px;

    overflow: hidden;
}

 #DIV_9 {
    max-height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    max-width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: -20px;
 }
```